# Firebase-Firestore not loading 2 documents' information simultaneously

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Good morning

So, I am able to load information from my firebase documents and collections, to a certain extent...

When my collections have 1 Document, everything goes smoothly.
When it has more than 1 Document, well, the app breaks.

So, I have this:

```
db.collection("KitListCategorie").get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        for (document1 in snapshot.documents) {
            val data1 = document1.data
            val weights = data1["categoryName"] as String
            val misc = data1["categoryName"] as String

            categorySpinnerArray.add(weights)
            categorySpinnerArray.add(misc)


        }
        categorySpinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

For this Firestore setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP3r5.jpg

Then I get this error:    `kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a simply misstake. In you screenshot in Firebase you field "categoryName" entitled as "categoryname" so it's return null and kotlin throw exception.

Comment: Omg... can't believe I was missing something like that! :O It was right in front of me. Thanks. Going to test it out

Comment: Problem solved, so simple!! :D Curious thing, I only need one val for all the items with the same Key right? :D

Comment: @EduardoGuterres Of Course for this case you have loop. Enjoy firebase and kotlin:D

Comment: Any idea why my second spinner shows up empty until I click? And if I select an item it doesn't show up? :/ https://imgur.com/a/7WDbF

Comment: @EduardoGuterres Check with debug is your retrieved data from firebase is correct. Then create a new question. Provide you code with problem and describe result that you want to achieve. Sorry mate but now I can't help you because i have no clue what do you want. I GUESS that now you problem is that you use same adapter for each array and it's overwrite each other.

Comment: That's cool. I debugged it and I was able to see where the value was getting "lost". Thanks anyways